# Powerapps Filter Gallery by TextInput And/Or TextInput & ComboBox

Tags: combobox, gallery, powerapps, textinput, powerapps-formula

I am trying to filter a powerapps gallery by either TextInput And/Or TextInput & ComboBox the code below only filters by textinput can anyone help?

```
Filter(
   WD_Stock_Items_SP_List,
    TextInput1.Text in Item_Description || TextInput1.Text in Item_Description && 
    ComboBox1.Selected.Value)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
With( { f1: Filter(WD_Stock_Items_SP_List, TextInput1.Text in Item_Description ) },
  If(
    CountRows(ComboBox1.SelectedItems) > 0,
    Filter(f1, yourColumnName.Value = First(ComboBox1.SelectedItems).Value),
    f1
  )
)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you